# git (1.7.11.7) show doesn't work properly for me

Tags: git

I apologize if this has been brought up before, but I've searched and not found a similar problem/solution...

When I run `git show HEAD~n:file_path` on my project (various values for `n`), it always shows me the latest revision. I can't get it to show any earlier revisions at all. I've tried `HEAD{date}` and `HEAD^^^^`... etc and the same thing occurs. I have the syntax correct as it does give me a result, not an error. It's just that the result is always the latest file. I did a `git log file_path` to see the revision log and there are revisions there. If I pluck out a date, say, 10 revisions back and do `HEAD{that_date}` it still just shows me the current revision. I also tried `git show origin~n:file_path` and `git show master~n:file_path` (with various values of `n`) and same thing.

So, I'm perplexed. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: If it's a bug then most people would ask you to try the latest git version (1.8.x at this time)

Comment: Don't have much to help, but `git show HEAD~1:file` and `git show HEAD:file` produced the proper results on git 1.7.12.4.

Comment: Thanks guys. I am not currently claiming a bug in git at this point. My first assumption is that there must be something wrong with what I'm doing, but just not sure what it is yet. These are pretty fundamental commands and I would be surprised if they didn't work out of the box. Maybe I'll keep playing with it and see what I can figure out.

Comment: Try `git show <sha1>:file_path`, where `<sha1>` is a commit id of a revision you are sure that it has another content.

Comment: Thanks kan. That actually shows correct output. I looked at two sha1 settings based upon what `git log file_path` told me. They were adjacent in the change chain. The later one showed the change, and the former did not. Just as I expected. If I then try to do this using the HEAD~n nomenclature, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I just did

```
 git checkout v1.7.11.7
 git clean -dfx
 make CFLAGS=-march=native\ -Os\ -pipe -j5 install
 git --version
 git show HEAD~10:git.c >f1
 git show HEAD~900:git.c >f2
 diff f1 f2
```

and got differences.

Comment: As an aside, you could avoid the intermediate files with `diff <(git show HEAD~10:git.c) <(git show HEAD~900:git.c)`.